# How can I have partially centered, partially bottom aligned content?

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML div (parent) that contains 3 children. Each of these children contain an image and a text. The image can be either small/medium/large and its height reflect the size. My goal is to make the images align to the center while the texts are aligned on the bottom. This is the starting point I had created:
https://codepen.io/giorgi-tediashvili/pen/KKwjrzr

```css
#parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.smallImage {
  height: 30px;
}

.mediumImage {
  height: 70px;
}

.largeImage {
  height: 110px;
}

.child {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child child1">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" class="smallImage" />
    <br/>
    <text>Small</text>
  </div>
  <div class="child child2">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" class="mediumImage" />
    <br/>
    <text>Medium</text>
  </div>
  <div class="child child3">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" class="largeImage" />
    <br/>
    <text>Large</text>
  </div>
</div>
```

Screenshot:

[image]
And the Desired outcome:

[image]

Comment: your pen seems to be the same as your desired outcome, did you figure it out?

Comment: @capote1789 No, the pen is showing the top screenshot. The desired outcome is the bottom screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like below using flexbox as nested container:

```css
#parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.smallImage {
  height: 30px;
}

.mediumImage {
  height: 70px;
}

.largeImage {
  height: 110px;
}

.child {
  padding: 10px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
img {
  margin:auto;
}
span {
 text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child child1">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" class="smallImage" >
    <span>Small</span>
  </div>
  <div class="child child2">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" class="mediumImage" >
    <span>Medium</span>
  </div>
  <div class="child child3">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" class="largeImage" >
    <span>Large</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice, I was just about to answer with this too - key being margin: auto on the img

Answer (score 0):

I'd put the images and text in separate rows inside each column. The text row will collapse to the text height and you can vertically center the images.

```css
.flex-h {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: stretch;
}

.flex-v {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.flex-v :first-child {
    flex: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-self: center;
}

.flex-v :last-child {
    flex: none;
}

.smallImage {
    height: 30px;
}

.mediumImage {
    height: 70px;
}

.largeImage {
    height: 110px;
}

.child {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-h">
    <div class="flex-v">
        <div class="child child1">
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" class="smallImage" />
        </div>
        <div class="child child1">
            <text>Small</text>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex-v">
        <div class="child child2">
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" class="mediumImage" />
        </div>
        <div class="child child1">
            <text>Medium</text>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex-v">
        <div class="child child3">
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" class="largeImage" />
        </div>
        <div class="child child1">
            <text>Large</text>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this is close but images are still aligned on top line instead of middle

Comment: Oops. I lost that in my fiddling. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

I messed with the padding a little, I think it seems closer:

```
.parent {
 display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: stretch;
}

.smallImage{
height: 30px;
padding-bottom: 30px;
padding-right: 10px;
}
.mediumImage{
height: 70px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
}
.largeImage{
height: 110px;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
}

.child {
padding: 10px;
}
.v-center {
align-items: center;
}
```